# How to disable back arrow in DrawerLayout using Navigation Controller with fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout

I would like to prevent creating the backstack. I do not want the back arrow button to show up. What is the most elegant way to do this?

My code in Activity `OnCreate()`

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
navigationView= findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController, drawerLayout)
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,drawerLayout)

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

And I navigate fragments using:

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
    .navigate(R.id.myCollectionFragment)
```

Comment: What do you want to show up instead? Do you want the drawer icon to continue to be displayed? Did you want to not have any icon at all? Please be specific.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, I had the drawer icon (hamburger) show up. I would like to keep it displayed at all items